Pass data from child component to parent component
I have a parent React component with 2 child components containing dropdowns in each. The values in the second dropdown component depend on the value chosen in the first dropdown components. How do I pass that value from child dropdown 1  up to the parent so that I can choose what values to display in dropdown 2
ie. if country chosen in parent AddressCreator is 'US' then show StateSelector child component. else show ProvinceSelector child component
export function AddressCreator({ name }: AddressCreatorProps): React.JSX.Element {

  
  return (
    <div>
      <CountryDropdown
        items={countryDropdownItems}
        labelText='Select a country'
      ></CountryDropdown>
      {selectedItem.toString().includes('US') ? (
        <StateSelector labelText='Select a state'> 
        </StateSelector>
      ) : (
        <ProvinceSelector labelText='Select a province'>  
        </ProvinceSelector>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}


To pass data from a child component to a parent component in React, you can use a callback function provided by the parent component.
// Child component for selecting a country
function CountryDropdown({ items, labelText, onCountryChange }) {
  const handleChange = (event) => {
    // Call the function passed from the parent with the new value
    onCountryChange(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <label>{labelText}</label>
      <select onChange={handleChange}>
        {items.map((item) => (
          <option key={item} value={item}>
            {item}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>
    </div>
  );
}

// Parent component
export function AddressCreator({ name }) {
  const [selectedCountry, setSelectedCountry] = useState('');
  const countryDropdownItems = ['US', 'Canada', 'Mexico']; // example items

  // Callback function to handle country change
  const handleCountryChange = (country) => {
    setSelectedCountry(country);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <CountryDropdown
        items={countryDropdownItems}
        labelText='Select a country'
        onCountryChange={handleCountryChange}
      />
      {selectedCountry === 'US' ? (
        <StateSelector labelText='Select a state' />
      ) : (
        <ProvinceSelector labelText='Select a province' />
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

// Mock StateSelector component
function StateSelector({ labelText }) {
  return <div>{labelText}</div>;
}

// Mock ProvinceSelector component
function ProvinceSelector({ labelText }) {
  return <div>{labelText}</div>;
}

